# R software-Make table combining a table and a vector

Tags: r

I have :
1.

```
timestamp depth
1   2012-05-19 16:45:28-05 10.01
2   2012-05-19 10:45:18-05 10.01
3   2012-05-19 09:30:22-05  9.99
4   2012-05-19 09:15:21-05  9.99
5   2012-05-19 09:00:21-05  9.98
6   2012-05-19 08:45:20-05  9.99
7   2012-05-19 08:30:18-05  9.98
8   2012-05-19 08:15:19-05  9.99
9   2012-05-19 08:00:23-05  9.98
```

2.

```
d
  [1] 0.75 0.75 0.77 0.77 0.78 0.77 0.78 0.77 0.78
```

I want to join these and make

```
timestamp depth             d
1   2012-05-19 16:45:28-05 10.01        0.75
2   2012-05-19 10:45:18-05 10.01        0.75
3   2012-05-19 09:30:22-05  9.99        0.77
4   2012-05-19 09:15:21-05  9.99        0.77
5   2012-05-19 09:00:21-05  9.98        0.78
6   2012-05-19 08:45:20-05  9.99        0.77
7   2012-05-19 08:30:18-05  9.98        0.78
8   2012-05-19 08:15:19-05  9.99        0.77
9   2012-05-19 08:00:23-05  9.98        0.78
```

How do I do that?

Comment: I really would suggest you reform your question using the coding tool looks like this **{}**   Right now it's hard to tell what's going on and what you want.

Comment: I want to do this:
In R software:
How do I join a table(A) and vector to obtain a table having columns from table(A) and vector as a column in the new table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:
x is your dataframe.

```
newdataframe= data.frame(x, newcol)
```

Answer (score 3):

If your timestamp & depth data is `df.timestamp.depth` and the vector data is called `vector`, simply:

```
combined.df <- data.frame(df.timestamp.depth, vector)
```

Comment: If I have a list of names and I need to pull out one the names, say: Name[1] which has value say ABC.
Then I want to use it as:
ABC= table we obtained earlier
How to do that?

Comment: Do you want to use the name to refer to a column of the table or a value in a column in the table?

Comment: I want to name the table. The name should come from the value in vector containing names.
Lets Name is vector containing all the names.
I want to name this table as Name[1].
How to do that?

Comment: names(table) will give you the names of the table.
names(table) <- vectorofnames will rename the table

Comment: Your question is FAQ 7.21 "How can I turn a string into a variable?"

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a `cbind` operation

If those are data.frames named df1 and df2 (or a vector named df2) then try:

```
 new <- cbind(df1,d=df2)
```